# Load a different TPL according to window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, smarty

I try to load a different TPL according to the window width (or I can also set a variable).
So, I suppose I can use a code like that or get at least 2 different kind of window:

Basically, this is the result I would like to have:

```
if($(window).width() < 960){
  include file="small.tpl"
};

else{
 include file="big.tpl"
};
```

or something like that:

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) 
   {assign var="numcolumns" value="1"};

else 
  {assign var="numcolumns" value="2"};
```

Any easy suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but it won't work this way. You cannot load PHP (and Smarty is de facto PHP) using JavaScript conditions.

The best you can do, is to include both files and depending on detecting window with in JavaScript to hide unwanted block.

However it's not the best technique. I would recommend you using Responsive Web Design technique to display site no matter of client window width.

**EDIT**

Working code (without using jQuery)

```
<div id="big">
   {include file="big.tpl"}
</div>
<div id="small">
   {include file="small.tpl"}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">


if (window.innerWidth < 960) 
    document.getElementById('big').style.display = 'none';
else 
    document.getElementById('small').style.display = 'none';

</script>
```

Comment: Actually the responsive design (and Im good with it) its not the best solution.

However it's not the best technique. I would recommend you using Responsive Web Design technique to display site no matter of client window width

Comment: How can I include both files and then hide the unwanted tpl??

Comment: @user3848253 I've added sample code. There is no best solution, but in the case I showed you load the same/similar content twice what mean that page is loaded longer and you only use a half of your content

Comment: I dont exactly understand what you mean with your last comment. anyway seams the javascript is not able to select the div. Ive every time both div printed in the page

Comment: @user3848253 I've updated code but it doesn't use jQuery. You should change your browser window width to see effect. Of course if you resize window you need to refresh page to see effect

Comment: no way. I post the script before to close head, but in my page I every time load both the tpl

Comment: @user3848253 I've already told you that both files will be loaded and Javascript only will hide one of them. This code is working - if you put it into one template file (and assuming you don't have any `big` and `small` ids on your website it will work).

Comment: I understand the script should just hide one of the div, but actualy in the page where I place the code I dont have what I suppose to get

Comment: @user3848253 So I cannot help you then. When I put this code into Smarty TPL file it works for me, it includes both files and hide one of divs.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Javascript

```
<div id="big">
   {include file="big.tpl"}
</div>
<div id="small">
   {include file="small.tpl"}
</div>
```

Just use CSS

```
#big {
    display: block;
}
#small {
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    #big {
        display: none;
    }
    #small {
        display: block;
    }
    
}
```